# Javascript :Connect to login form with an API doesn't run

Tags: javascript, html

I use javascript to connect to a login. I put console.log on the password and the email and apparently it recovers the password well but not the email and I don't see where the problem comes from. I checked my email Id in the HTML and javascript code and nothing. Can you help me ? And tell me what's wrong with my code. Thank you and good day

I changed getElementById by querySelector but nothing. My email Id is well written however everywhere. Here is the HTML

```
<form class="form" action="#" method="post">
                        <h3>Log In</h3>
                        <div class="input">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" id="password">
                            <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" id="submit">
                            <p id="errorMessage"></p>
                            <a class="link" href="#" >Mot de passe oublié</a>
                            <p id="erreur"></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is the javascript code

```
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
 const errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
 submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    console.log("email: ", email);
    console.log("password: ", password);
    if (!email || !password) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs";
        return;
    }
    fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/users/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
        })
        .then(authResponse => {
            console.log("authResponse: ", authResponse);
            if (authResponse.status === 200) {
                return authResponse.json();
            }
            else if (authResponse.status === 401) {
            errorMessage.textcontent = "Accès non autrorisé";
            }
            else if (authResponse.status === 404) {
            errorMessage.textcontent = "Utilisateur non trouvé";
            } else {
            errorMessage.textcontent = `Error: ${authResponse.status}`;
            }
            })
            .then(userData => {
                console.log("userData: ", userData);
                if (userData) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));
                window.location.replace = "admin.html";
            }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        });
```

Here is a screenshot of console :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXcwL.png)

Comment: you probably have something, somewhere with `id="email"` try changing your input to `id="email2"`, just for testing purposes and see if that works.

Comment: problem Solve. thank you rick. It was the solution to add an different id, i put id="email2"

Answer (score 1):

Replace: `const submit = document.getElementById("submit");` by: `const submit = document.querySelector(".form");`

And
`submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {` by:  `submit.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {`

Here is the full JS:

```
const submit = document.querySelector(".form");
 const errorMessage = document.getElementById("errorMessage");
 submit.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    console.log("email: ", email);
    console.log("password: ", password);
    if (!email || !password) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs";
        return;
    }
    fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/users/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
        })
        .then(authResponse => {
            console.log("authResponse: ", authResponse);
            if (authResponse.status === 200) {
                return authResponse.json();
            }
            else if (authResponse.status === 401) {
            errorMessage.textcontent = "Accès non autrorisé";
            }
            else if (authResponse.status === 404) {
            errorMessage.textcontent = "Utilisateur non trouvé";
            } else {
            errorMessage.textcontent = `Error: ${authResponse.status}`;
            }
            })
            .then(userData => {
                console.log("userData: ", userData);
                if (userData) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));
                window.location.replace = "admin.html";
            }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        });
```

https://codepen.io/Echyzen/pen/xxJaVzE

Comment: I have the same error, it recovers the password well but not the email.

Comment: You must have done something else because in the codepen it works I add you this one:
https://codepen.io/Echyzen/pen/xxJaVzE

Comment: thank you Echyzen
problem solved i changed email ID for email2 in both code HTML and javascript